# How to define a custom split in tensorflow datasets?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am walking through the docs of the new Tensorflow datasets library, trying to add a new dataset. I want to specify custom dataset splits for my own dataset and in the docs they say:

> If the dataset comes with pre-defined splits (for example, MNIST has
>   train and test splits), keep those splits in the `DatasetBuilder`. If
>   this is your own data and you can decide your own splits, we suggest
>   using a split of (`TRAIN:80%, VALIDATION: 10%, TEST: 10%`). Users can
>   always get subsplits through `tfds.Split.subsplit`.

I am using `GeneratorBasedBuilder`, which is a subclass of `tfds.core.DatasetBuilder` that simplifies defining a dataset. Thus, I have to implement the method `_split_generators`, which is show below:

```
def _split_generators(self, dl_manager):
    # Download source data
    extracted_path = dl_manager.download_and_extract(...)

    # Specify the splits
    return [
        tfds.core.SplitGenerator(
            name="train",
            num_shards=10,
            gen_kwargs={
                "images_dir_path": os.path.join(extracted_path, "train"),
                "labels": os.path.join(extracted_path, "train_labels.csv"),
            },
        ),
        tfds.core.SplitGenerator(
            name="test",
            num_shards=1,
            gen_kwargs={
                "images_dir_path": os.path.join(extracted_path, "test"),
                "labels": os.path.join(extracted_path, "test_labels.csv"),
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Is there a way to specify custom splits this way or I should inherit from the lower level `DatasetBuilder` class?